# Why give a variable a null value when declaring it?

Tags: c

I noticed that many times when declaring variables/arrays/etc, people give it a null value or 0.

for example, take a look at the following snippet:

```
int nNum = 0;
char cBuffer[10] = { 0 };
int *nPointer = NULL;
```

and etc.

Untill asking this question I figured it would be for debugging purposes, since when I 
was debugging a program with Visual Studio I noticed that variables that had no value had
undefined numbers as their value, whilst with 0 they had... 0.

Comment: Initializing a variable is ALWAYS a good habit. Checking if a pointer is NULL allow you to allocate the data you need if you haven't allocated it yet.

Comment: for me it's like asking: why give a variable *any* value when declaring it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of reasons to initialize variables to 0 or NULL.

First of all, remember that unless it's declared at file scope (outside of any function) or with the `static` keyword, a variable will contain an *indeterminate* value; it may be 0, it may be 0xDEADBEEF, it may be something else.

For sums, counters, and the like, you want to make sure you start from 0, otherwise you will get an invalid result:

```
int sum = 0;
while ( not_at_end_of_things_to_sum )
  sum += next_thing_to_sum;

int count = 0;
while ( there_is_another_thing_to_count )
  count++;
```

etc.

Granted, you don't *have* to initialize these kinds of variables as part of the declaration; you just want to make sure they're zeroed out before you use them, so you could write

```
int count;
...
count = 0;
while ( there_is_another_thing_to_count )
  count++;
```

it's just that by doing it as part of the declaration, you don't have to worry about it later.

For arrays intended to hold strings, it's to make sure that there's a 0 terminator if you're building a string without using `strcpy` or `strcat` or `scanf` or similar:

```
char buf[N] = { 0 }; // first element is *explicitly* initialized to 0, 
                     // remaining elements are *implicitly* initialized to 0

while ( not_at_end_of_input && i < N - 1 )
  buf[i++] = next_char;
```

You don't *have* to do it this way, but otherwise you'd have to be sure to add the 0 terminator manually:

```
buf[i] = 0;
```

For pointers, it's to make it easy to test if a pointer is valid or not.  A NULL pointer is a well-defined *invalid* pointer value that's easy to test against:

```
char *p = NULL;
...
if ( !p ) // or p == NULL )
{
  // p has not yet been assigned or allocated
  p = malloc( ... );
}
```

Otherwise, it's effectively impossible to tell if the pointer value is valid (points to an object or memory allocated with `malloc`) or not.

Comment: A very helpful explaination, cleared everything up, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

An uninitialized pointer variable may contain a garbage value. The purpose of initializing a pointer with `NULL` is that if you inadvertently use it without assigning a proper address, you do not end up modifying the contents at a random memory address.

Comment: that's **one** of the resasons.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath Can you please elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the language, you would use `NULL` or just `int *nPointer;`

it's called initializing a variable, i.e. you're creating it. This is extremely helpful if you want your program to remain at a constant state, knowing that "un-initialized" variables won't cause an exception.

If you're inializing a varibale inside a loop or function, and you want to use it outside that loop/function and the loop/function only executes when there's a condition attached to it e.g:

```
if(nNum != 0){
    int *nPointer = NULL;
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
        *nPointer++;
    }
}
```

In this case if you did not initialize your variable, and you try and use it later down the line, your program might break. However, if it has been initialized, your safe, knowing it exists, but is still `NULL`.

SAFER CODE:

```
int *nPointer = NULL; //Or this will be a class member
if(nNum != 0){
     for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
         *nPointer++;
     }
 }
```